# How do I collapse schemas in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am not sure if this is possible, but I am hoping it is - I am currently running SSMS and have a database that has it's data all "housed" in the DBO schema.  I have received advice (and completely agree) that best practice will be to create additional schema's that match our business functions, and I will be moving ahead with that.

I would like to know if there is any way - even if it is by install an add-in of some kind, to have the schema collapse so that I can have all the DBO, and RPT objects hidden until I expand the schema - much like the tables and other folders are collapsed.

I apologise if this question is not quite "on topic" for this site - but I think this is where the answer is most likely to be known.

In my screenshot below - I am looking for the bit outlined in red to be collapsedand there just to be 2 lines the DBO that is there now - and the RPT which I currently have the request in to create:

[image]

Comment: Be aware that your developers will hate you if they have to change all statements.

Comment: Luckily for me, this is at the very beginning stage ATM - and I am really the only developer working on it.  So now is the right time to make such a fundamental change.  (I have actually in between original post and this comment implemented a few SCHEMA  names eg DIM, FACT)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a bit of hunting after @LowlyDBA gave his answer, and came across an extension to SSMS that does exactly what I was looking for!

[SSMS Schema Folders](https://github.com/nicholas-ross/SSMS-Schema-Folders)

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can come would be to filter out those schemas temporarily:

1. Right click on "Tables".
2. Select "Filter -> Filter Settings" and filter out the schema you don't want to see.

[image]

This should apply to all reasonably recent versions of SSMS.

Most generic DB tools that work with multiple products will offer this ability since they often utilize the schema concept more - you could try a different tool (like 0xDBE or something similar) if you really want this functionality, but you'd be giving up a lot of the MSSQL-specific functions of SSMS.

Comment: This will certainly help - but it would be nice if someone has written an extension that does what I want...  I do like the SSMS way of working but there are some things that it could do just a tiny bit better...